# Received a label value of 50 which is outside the valid range of [0, 50)

Tags: python, binary-data, biometrics

There is a database of 500 240*240 binary biometric images that I want to use to create a neural network (50 people with 10 photos each). I can't train the neural network because I get errors. Please help me to write the correct code for learning. Perhaps you have examples for me.
I'm getting an error

```
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1830] OP_REQUIRES failed at sparse_xent_op.cc:103 : INVALID_ARGUMENT: Received a label value of 50 which is outside the valid range of [0,  50).  Label values: 9 30 7 6 24 40 50 16 9 12 42 34 29 34 29 16 40 43 44 44 42 43 50 33 27 31 41 31 13 13 23 7 Backend TkAgg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.
```

```
Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\runpy.py", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\runpy.py", line 88, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "c:\Users\1\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy\__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
      cli.main()
    File "c:\Users\1\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
      run()
    File "c:\Users\1\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher/../..\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 284, in run_file
      runpy.run_path(target, run_name="__main__")
    File "c:\Users\1\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 321, in run_path
      return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
    File "c:\Users\1\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 135, in _run_module_code
      _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
    File "c:\Users\1\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.6.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 124, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "D:\1\Desktop\Python\exp13-1.py", line 86, in <module>
      model.fit(x_train, y_train1, epochs=10)
    File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1685, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1284, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1268, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1249, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1051, in train_step
      loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1109, in compute_loss
      return self.compiled_loss(
    File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py", line 265, in __call__
      loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 142, in __call__
      losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 268, in call
      return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 2078, in sparse_categorical_crossentropy
      return backend.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(
    File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\keras\backend.py", line 5660, in sparse_categorical_crossentropy
      res = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
Node: 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits'
Received a label value of 50 which is outside the valid range of [0, 50).  Label values: 9 30 7 6 24 40 50 16 9 12 42 34 29 34 29 16 40 43 44 44 42 43 50 33 27 31 41 31 13 13 23 7
     [[{{node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1471]
```

My array

```
trainX = trainX/255.0
testX = testX/255.0
trainY = np.arraytrainY, dtype=np.uint8)
testY = np.array(testY, dtype=np.uint8)
```

Neural network

```
def create_model(input_shape):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation='sigmoid')
    ])
    return model

input_shape = (240, 240, 1) 
model = create_model(input_shape)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=10)
```

Comment: sparse_categorical_crossentropy expects values from 0 up to 49 (which is clearly written in `Received a label value of 50 which is outside the valid range of [0,  50)` (note that 50 is not included). Do you have y labels numbered from 1 to 50?

Comment: Yes, the testY looks like this:
[ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9. 10. 11. 12. 13. 14. 15. 16. 17. 18.
 19. 20. 21. 22. 23. 24. 25. 26. 27. 28. 29. 30. 31. 32. 33. 34. 35. 36.
 37. 38. 39. 40. 41. 42. 43. 44. 45. 46. 47. 48. 49. 50.]

Comment: Subtract 1 from testY and you should be going with that